# Match instances of "foo" not followed by "bar"

Tags: r, regex

How can I match strings that have "foo" followed by something other than "bar" (with a word boundary at the end of foo)?

Examples

```
library(stringr)
str_detect("foo 123", "\\bfoo\\b^(bar)")  # should be TRUE
str_detect("foo", "\\bfoo\\b^(bar)")  # should be TRUE
str_detect("foo bar", "\\bfoo\\b^(bar)")  # should be FALSE
```

Obviously what I've tried, `\\bfoo\\b^(bar)` is not correct.

Comment: So bar can't appear anywhere following foo? Or just the word after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a negative Lookahead, you can use something like this:

```
\bfoo\b(?!\W+bar)
```

[Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/j9hMO3/2).

Obviously, if `\` is illegal in R, you'd need to escape it, so you'd use `\\bfoo\\b(?!\\W+bar)` instead.

---

If `bar` also must be a whole word, you can add an extra `\b` at the end:

```
\bfoo\b(?!\W+bar\b)
```

[Another demo](https://regex101.com/r/j9hMO3/3).

Answer (score 0):

In the general case, to detect the presence of a `foo`  not followed with `bar` (anywhere to the right of `foo`), you may use a base R `grep` with the `perl=TRUE` argument:

```
x <- c("foo bar", "foo")
grep("(?s)foo(?!.*bar)", x, perl=TRUE, value=TRUE)
```

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/IYPbGU)

The `(?!.*bar)` is a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#negative). It only asserts the absence of some pattern *after* the current regex engine position, i.e. it checks and returns true if there is no match, otherwise it returns false. Thus, it does not not "consume" characters, the regex engine stays at the same location in the input string. In this regex, it is the position after `foo`. So, right after `foo`, the regex engine starts looking for `.*` (any character including a newline (due to the `DOTALL` `(?s)` inline modifier), 0 or more repetitions), and then tries to match `bar`. Thus, if there is `bar`, there will be no match since the lookahead will return *false*.

To match these words as whole words, do not forget `\b` on both ends of each word in the pattern (as Ahmed indicated in his answer, too).

NOTE: If there can be only a specific set of chars between `foo` and `bar`, use a specific pattern rather than `.*`:

```
foo(?!\s+bar) - no "bar" after "foo" separated with 1+ whitespaces from it
foo(?!\W+bar) - no "bar" after "foo" separated with 1+ non-word chars from it
foo(?!\w*bar) - no "bar" after "foo" in the same "word" (digits, letters, _)
foo(?!\p{L}*bar) - no "bar" after "foo" in the same letter-word
```

Yes, do not forget to double escape backslashes in R code.